# Is setTime is equivalent to (setHour,setMinutes,setSeconds) in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am writing some global function for my application there I made one function for setHour,setMinute,setSecond that is below :

```
function SetJSDateFromHrMinSecToHrMinSec(destDT, sourceDT, strTz) {
    destDT.setHours(sourceDT.getHours());
    destDT.setMinutes(sourceDT.getMinutes());
    destDT.setSeconds(sourceDT.getSeconds());
}
```

so wherever in application these three are getting implemented I am simply calling my function and do the rest like

```
SetJSDateFromHrMinSecToHrMinSec(dtEndTime,dtStartTime+10,strTZ);
```

but I encounter with setTime in same application

```
apptdt.setTime(dt.getHours(), dt.getMinutes(), 0, null);
```

and I am not aware of setTime I have doubt like it will do the same as my function which comprises all,so can I use my function for it also.

Comment: [setHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) accepts minutes and second as well.

Comment: [definition of `setTime()`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.settime). That's not the correct way to call it.

Comment: @Barmar can you please elaborate a bit I searched it in google but not find that much help...so kindly help.

Comment: Did you try googling for `javascript date settime"? It finds https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime

Comment: Both of these say that `setTime()` just takes one argument, which is the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for the link

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the complete time via one method you can use `setHours` as it takes multiple arguments. `setTime` sets Epoch value and takes only one argument.

A better solution could be to use `setHours` and pass all the values separated by space:

```js
function SetJSDateFromHrMinSecToHrMinSec(destDT, sourceDT, strTz) {
 destDT.setHours(sourceDT.getHours(),sourceDT.getMinutes(),sourceDT.getSeconds()
)}
```